# Загрузка png через url в имеющийся imageview

Tags: java, android

Надо просто загрузить *png*-картинку через *url* в уже существующий *imageview*.

Попробовал, как сказали [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android). Картинки `.jpg` отлично грузит и отображает, а формата `.png` не хочет отображать, получается пустой экран (протестировал на версиях 4.1 и 4.2).

Почему так происходит и как это исправить?

```
if (isOnline()) {
        new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewSA))
                .execute(img);
    } else {
        tv_info.setText("Включите интернет для загрузки");
    }

}

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }


    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);

    }
}
```

Comment: Используйте picasso или universal image loader

Comment: Да, спасибо большое, использовал [Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) - очень удобная библиотека для загрузки картинок! Сильно она меня выручила!

Comment: =) незачто. Сам ей пользуюсь

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), он наиболее прост, "кодоэкономен" и стабилен.

В раздел dependencies (build.gradle)
добавьте библиотеку

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Затем в коде импорируйте:

```
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
```

и используйте

```
ImageView shopLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewLogo);
Picasso.with(this).load(logoURL).into(shopLogo);
```

Для картинки по умолчанию есть .placeholder, а для картинки при ошибке загрузки есть .error

```
Picasso
.with(this)
.load(logoURL)
.placeholder(getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.default_photo))
.error(getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.default_photo))
.into(shopLogo);
```